# Why is retry_interval undefined in subsequent calls using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a problem with setTimeout which is called from within a function.  setTimeout makes a recursive call to the get_zone_counts function (only in error case).  On the first time setTimeout is called the retry_delay argument is set correctly as per the first call of the function.  But in subsequent calls to setTimeout the retry_delay argument is undefined.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Here is the code:

```
const request = require('request');

// server not connected for this test
const url = "http://192.168.1.23/api/data/live?format=JSON";

function handle_zone_count_response(body, container) {
    // this function simply parses the response message
    console.log("handle_zone_count_response called");
}

function get_zone_counts(url, retry_delay) {
    request.get(url, function(error, res, body) {
        if(error) {
        console.log("error: ", error);
        console.log(`setting timer to retry zone count requests in ${retry_delay} msecs`);
        // set timer to try again after retry_delay
        setTimeout(get_zone_counts, retry_delay, url);
        } else {
            console.log(body);
            handle_zone_count_response(body, zone_counts);
        // print zone_counts
            console.log("zone counts: ", zone_counts);
        }
    });
}

get_zone_counts(url, 5000);
```

Example output:

```
error:  { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.168.1.23:80
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1024:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1195:14)
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '192.168.1.23',
  port: 80 }
setting timer to retry zone count requests in 5000 msecs
error:  { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.168.1.23:80
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1024:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1195:14)
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '192.168.1.23',
  port: 80 }
setting timer to retry zone count requests in undefined msecs
error:  { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.168.1.23:80
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1024:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1195:14)
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '192.168.1.23',
  port: 80 }
setting timer to retry zone count requests in undefined msecs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recursive call is

```
setTimeout(get_zone_counts, retry_delay, url);
```

That means: call `get_zone_counts` after `retry_delay` ms with a parameter of `url`. That is, `retry_delay` is not being passed to any subsequent calls.

If you want to pass the same `retry_delay` as in the initial call to the recursive call, add it to the end of the `setTimeout` parameter list:

```
setTimeout(get_zone_counts, retry_delay, url, retry_delay);
```

This is basically the same as

```
setTimeout(() => get_zone_counts(url, retry_delay), retry_delay);
```

which might look a bit more intuitive.